# Document Set Content Types Missing From Parent Content Type

Tags: 2013, document, document-set

I am trying to create new Document set Content type but for some reason i can see option to create one when i go to Site Contents-> New Site Content Type
[image]

But the weird thing is i already have tons of Document Set Content type in the site and feature is enabled in Site Collection Features. How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that someone accidentally changed the group of the default Document Set content type to something else?  That could cause it not to show up in this list.  You can navigate to the content type and see the group setting - maybe that will help you:

```
Link: {your site url}/_layouts/15/ctypedit.aspx?ctype=0x0120D520
```